# Closed-form expression for Poisson-Binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, poisson-distribution

I'm interesting in knowing whether there is a closed-form expression for the following series:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n!}\lambda^n e^{-\lambda} \left[{n \choose k}z^k(1-z)^{n-k} \right] $

I've made some progress simplifying...

$ = \left( \frac{z}{1-z} \right)^ke^{-\lambda}\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^n$

...but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It ultimately comes down to finding closed form for $\sum_n \frac{1}{n!(n-k)!} x^n$, where $x$ is a parameter

Comment: Right---this is as far as I got. I'll update the original post to reflect this...

Comment: @Jakobian, not exactly, it should be $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^n}{(n-k)!}$, there's no extra $n!$

Comment: According to my experiments with WolframAlpha, we have $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ for $k=1,2,3,4,\dots$

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks for your comments. Regarding the first, I got $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{x^n}{k!(n-k)!}$, which has an extra $k!$ relative to what you wrote. I've added this to the post...am I making an error?

Comment: @YuriyS Regarding your second comment: I'm seeing the same thing in WolframAlpha. How should I interpret this? When I do it with $k$ as a parameter (instead of k=1,2,3,...) I don't get the result. Is this a limitation of WolframAlpha or something to expect?

Comment: @John, the factor $1/k!$ doesn't depend on $n$ and so can be brought out of the summation. As for the result, it's not a limitation of WA, as for general $k$ the expression is more complicated (with gamma functions). For positive integer $k$ it's more simple, which I guess is your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that you have already had the prove. I start from:

$\left( \frac{z}{1-z} \right)^k \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{(n-k)!}\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^n=e^{-\lambda} \frac{{z}^k}{k!}\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\tag1$

Reindexing the series, introducing $m=n-k$

$e^{-\lambda} \frac{{z}^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{m=n-k}^\infty \frac{\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^{m}}{m!}\tag2$

As n start from 1 to $\infty$, m will start from

$1-k, 2-k, .....-2,-1, 0, 1, 2, .....\infty\tag3$

It means that we can devide the sum (2) into two parts:

$e^{-\lambda} \frac{{z}^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{k-1}\frac{\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^{-m}}{(-m)!}+e^{-\lambda} \frac{{z}^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]^{m}}{m!}\tag4$

The first sum  of (4) equal to zero, because $ (-m)!\rightarrow \infty$  because m integer.

Finally we get:

$e^{-\lambda} \dfrac{{z}^k}{k!}e^{\left[ \lambda(1-z) \right]}= \dfrac{{z}^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda z}\tag5$